# Как решить ошибку AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'file_path' на питоне

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

фрагмент кода:

```
async def transcribe_voice(file_id):
    file_info = bot.get_file_url(file_id)
    file_path = file_info.file_path
    url = f'https://api.telegram.org/file/bot{bot}/{file_path}'
```

ошибка:

```
  File "C:\Users\Аdmin\PycharmProjects\SIRI_YA_Bot\main.py", line 24, in transcribe_voice
    file_path = file_info.file_path
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'file_path'
```

пробовал заавэйтить `file_info = bot.get_file_url(file_id)`, но тот пишет ошибку

```
File "C:\Users\Аdmin\PycharmProjects\SIRI_YA_Bot\main.py", line 23, in transcribe_voice
    file_info = await bot.get_file_url(file_id)
TypeError: object str can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что тут должен существовать какой-то file_path?

Comment: мне нужно было загрузить голосовое сообщение из ТГ и я загружаю ГС с https://api.telegram.org/file/bot{bot}/{file_path} и я решил что это правильное решение

Comment: Просветите, кстати, я не в курсе, что значит "заавэйтить"?

Comment: без авэйта - file_info = bot.get_file_url(file_id)
с авэйтом -  file_info = await bot.get_file_url(file_id)

Comment: Ну так всё-таки почему вы решили, что тут должен существовать какой-то file_path?

Comment: И неужели дважды упомянутый `str` в текстах ошибок вам ни на что не намекает?

Comment: Не-а, можете разъяснить пожалуйста?

Comment: В моём коде, file_path используется для создания полного URL к файлу голосового сообщения. Этот URL затем используется в запросе requests.get, чтобы загрузить содержимое файла. Без file_path я не смогу точно определить местоположение файла и, следовательно, не смогу загрузить его.

Comment: Ну так вы всё-таки хорошенько подумайте, что возвращает функция `get_file_url` и что такое `file_info`?

Answer (score 0):

В твоём случае `file_info` - это просто строка, у нее нет атрибута `file_path`. Попробуй пересмотреть, что ты получаешь в `file_info` и достать путь до файла оттуда другим способом.